# RGB values to colour names in an android application

Tags: java, android, arrays, arraylist, camera

Wondering if I could get some advice or possibly some code examples regarding an android app I am developing. So I am making an Android app where the user can take photos and then identify the colours in the picture by pressing a button. The button is working fine and returning RGB values however I would like It to display the name of a colour instead. Im quite new to java and I thought maybe the best way was to use some form of array that lists different colours like this:

```
private ArrayList<ColorName> initColorList() {
    ArrayList<ColorName> colorList = new ArrayList<ColorName>();
    colorList.add(new ColorName("AliceBlue", 0xF0, 0xF8, 0xFF));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("Azure", 0xF0, 0xFF, 0xFF));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("Beige", 0xF5, 0xF5, 0xDC));
    colorList.add(new ColorName("Bisque", 0xFF, 0xE4, 0xC4));
    // Add more colors here
    return colorList;
```

and possibly some form of code that can choose to display the colour name closest to the resulting RGB values. Here is my current code...

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Bitmap bp = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");

    bmp = bp;

    imgFavorite.setImageBitmap(bp);
}

public void pix(){
    operation= Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp.getWidth(),
            bmp.getHeight(),bmp.getConfig());

    int height = bmp.getHeight();
    int width = bmp.getWidth();
    int p = bmp.getPixel(height / 2, width / 2);

    int r = Color.red(p);
    int g = Color.green(p);
    int b = Color.blue(p);

    Toast.makeText(this, String.valueOf(r) + String.valueOf(g) + String.valueOf(b), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Any help with this would be much appreciated!

Comment: the question is, how do you display the names of colours in the image view instead of RGB numbers ?

Answer (score 0):

you can do something really simple as implementing [hashCode and equals](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-collections/hashcode-equals.html) for your `ColorName`

```
public class ColorName {
private int r;
private int b;
private int g;

//Auto generated
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

    ColorName colorName = (ColorName) o;

    if (r != colorName.r) return false;
    if (b != colorName.b) return false;
    return g == colorName.g;

}
//Auto generated
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int result = r;
    result = 31 * result + b;
    result = 31 * result + g;
    return result;
}
```

}

then use [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) or some other map container like

```
Map<ColorName, String> myColorMap = new HashMap<>();
myColorMap.put(new ColorName(0xF0, 0xF8, 0xFF), "AliceBlue");...
```

when you will need some color name just use the map

```
String colorName = myColorMap.get(myColorNameObject);
```